# How to specify editor of document?

Tags: titles, koma-script, author

I am writing a document where I am the editor with (potential) many different authors. I was hoping there would be an `\editor{...}` command, that would complement the `\author{...}` command, but have yet to find anything.

I would like the editor to be mentioned on the title page of the document, probably under the title followed (on a new line) by the contributing authors.

**What have you done to specify the editor of a document in addition to the authors?**

I'm not necessarily looking for a package. If there is one, I'm happy to investigate it. If not, I'm equally happy to find "best practices" for specifying the editor of a document.

Comment: Where do you want to specify the editor in your document? On the titlepage? Perhaps `titling` is a useful package then

Comment: You can define an `\editor` command and use the `titling` package to define where it should appear in the `\maketitle` command.

Comment: While the `titling` package will work, it requires that I also specify a lot of other parameters for the styling of the authors. I'd rather not touch that. Also, it interferes with the `authblk` package.

Comment: what document class are you using?  it might be possible to patch the definition of `\maketitle` to add the editor information.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I’m using `scrartcl`

Comment: i'm not really well versed in `scrartcl` so i've added the tag `koma-script` to your question to attract users who are.

Comment: Can't you jhust add the editor to the author list? Where is the problem?